# PayPal server side confirmation

Tags: php, android, paypal

This part is kind of new for me, so this might be a very obvious answer. I used the PayPal MPL in my android application and on the server side in PHP I used this to get a verification of the payment:

```
function verify_paypal($payKey, $appID)
{
  global $payPalUser_Id, $payPalPassword, $payPalSig, $amount, $currency;
$headerArray = array(
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:'.$payPalUser_Id,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:'.$payPalPassword,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:'.$payPalSig,
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:'.$appID,
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT:NV',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:XML'
);

$url="https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails?payKey={$payKey}&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArray);

$adaptiveResponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (!is_null($adaptiveResponse)){

  //check result
  $dom_document = new DOMDocument();
  $dom_document->loadXML($adaptiveResponse);
  $searchNode = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName("responseEnvelope"); 

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) 
{ 
    $xmlResponse = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName( "ack" ); 
    $valueResponse = $xmlResponse->item(0)->nodeValue; 
} 

if (strtolower($valueResponse) =="failure"){
      return false;
    }

$xml=simplexml_load_string($adaptiveResponse);
$valueCurrency=$xml->currencyCode;
$valueStatus=$xml->status;

$searchNode = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName("receiver"); 

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) 
{ 
    $xmlAmount = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName( "amount" ); 
    $valueAmount = $xmlAmount->item(0)->nodeValue; 

    $xmlEmail = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName( "email" ); 
    $valueEmail = $xmlEmail->item(0)->nodeValue; 
} 

$searchNode = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName("paymentInfo"); 

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) 
{ 
    $xmlSenderStatus = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName( "senderTransactionStatus" ); 
    $valueSenderStatus = $xmlSenderStatus->item(0)->nodeValue;  
} 

if ((strtolower($valueStatus) =="completed")&&(strtolower($valueSenderStatus) =="completed")&&(strtolower($valueEmail) =="mymail@paypal.com")&&($valueAmount==$amount)&&($valueCurrency==$currency)){
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
}
return false;
};
```

But with the new Android SDK I get a PaymentConfirmation object:

```
PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
```

How am I supposed to get the $payKey from confirm or should I verify the payment in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of the MSDK you are using you may either need to use Adaptive Payments like you use to or REST API. Please check this page on how to verify payment https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Comment: OK - looks like I need to use this: confirm.getProofOfPayment().getPaymentId();

Comment: @Diego normally you would send to your server confirm.toJson() object and depending on the properties on environment take payment_id and than execute verification code against PayPal server See onActivityResult example here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md